# Taking too much time to load a page?

Tags: asp.net, pageload

I am a sever call in rowdatabound event. The page loads slowly because of multiple sever calls. How can i make the server call in page load. The queried data have to be accessed in row data bound. Any help appreciated....

```
protected void Grid_course_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    /*Tooltip.............................................*/
    connect con = new connect(date);
    Boolean bo = false;


    IList<connect.Courses> ob = con.getCoursedetails();
    Dictionary<string, string> tooltip = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < ob.Count; i++)
    {
        if (!tooltip.ContainsKey(ob[i].Name.ToString()))
        tooltip.Add(ob[i].Name.ToString(), ob[i].Course_Description__c.ToString());
    }
------------------
--------------------
}
```

The class connect connecting to salesforce and retrieving data.For each row bound it will query data from salesforce.

Comment: Show us code for multiple calls

Comment: How long does it take to connect? You are doing this once per row - there must be a better place to connect.

Answer (score 0):

For every row you are using

```
con.getCoursedetails();
```

Do you really want to show the entire records for every row?

As I can see, you are not passing any parameter to the function, so why cannot you call the method once and use the same result for every row as you are doing.

No need to get the data from database fro every row otherwise you need to pass some parameter to get the result only related to that row and that will get less record and your page will work better.